# get dropdownlist values from master page

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have dropdownlist in my master page which contains list of cities. Now from child pages anyone changes the cities then it shoul show only that cities data. but because my sql query code is on child page how can I connect masterPage dropdown with my child pages?

Answer (score -1):

In master page, create onselectedindex change event of dropdown and store selected value of dropdown in viewstate.

In master page create prerender event,

```
    Protected Sub Page_PreRender(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.PreRender
    ' here get viewstate value and filter data
    end sub
```

Comment: Not sure, but why did you mark my answer as not useful? I tested this and it works for me. If you have any difficulties, I can help you.